# Limit of natural log

Tags: harmonic-functions

Prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \ln x = \infty$ using the fact that the harmonic series diverges

Of course, this is obvious graphically, but I have to prove it formally. I based my thinking on this comment:

[image]

But I don't understand several things. First of all, why does $\displaystyle\frac{1}{x} > \frac{1}{2}$ imply that the integral is also greater than $1/2$? Secondly, if this is true, how do we use the result that the sum of the $1/x =$ the harmonic series diverges? Is the sum the same as the integral?

Is there a simpler solution to this question?

Comment: $f(x)\ge C $ gives $\int_{a}^b f(x) dx \ge (b-a)C$. Here, $b-a$ is 1 for all of your definite integrals.

Comment: Ok, would it be correct to sum up the integrals and say that the sum > the sum of c, which we know diverges?

Comment: That's the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\ln n=\int_1^n\dfrac{dt}t=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\int_{k}^{k+1}\dfrac{dt}t\geq\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\int_k^{k+1}\dfrac{dt}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\dfrac1{k}
$$

Comment: You are amazing...